# Salesforce1 Custom link

Tags: salesforce1-app, custom-link

there is an custom link which is redirect to the one visual page and visual page open the Iframe in that.

this functionality working correctly in the desktop app. but I open it into the salesforce1 app. its not working..

giving error - "Navigation URL not found"

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Navigation URL not found

Comment: Is the VF page a Flex Page or page that's enabled for SF1? If not, it won't be served from the SalesForce1 servers when called from a mobile device. See the Developing Mobile Apps Doc or the Administering SF1 Doc linked from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs.